# Deleting associated Data in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have two Models, `departments` and `users`. Departments is associated by hasMany with users and users belongsTo a department. Below is the snapshots of two table structures.

[image: users table][image: departments table]

department_id is foreign key in user table.When i delete the department ,the respective department_id  in user table not getting deleted.it stays as assigned before.How can i delete the department_id in users table.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, cakephp does not provide a mean to do that. You need to set SET NULL ON DELETE in the database.

Comment: I already set Null on department_id. Column..kindly check the image of user table..

Comment: U mean on delete method in controller, i have to update the field also

Comment: That was not the way. What you did is allow that column to be null.
You need to set the ability to revert to NULL if the parent record is deleted

Comment: Thanx bud but i am not sure this feature is available im xampp phpmyadmin...is it????

Comment: in the picture, i'm using sqlyog. It's database feature, i think it exists in phpmyadmin. Please look for it, and if it founded, please let me now.

It might reside in "relationships" section.

Comment: Okay ...sure I'll let u know.. Let me check it

Comment: Sorry bud...there is no such thing in phpmyadmin...there must be a way to do this by code..

Comment: i'll take a deep look at phpmyadmin and let you know. There must be.

Comment: structure > relation view